# TikZ: No visualize as smooth cycle option available

Tags: tikz-datavisualization

On page 858 the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) mentioned the option `visualize as smooth cycle` for the `\datavisualization[]{}` command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes,
                       visualize as smooth cycle
                      ]
    data {
          x, y
          0, 1
          1, 2
         };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems that the option istn't implemented. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you found a bug. You can cook up a visualizer of that type as follows.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\tikzdatavisualizationset{visualize as smooth cycle/.style={%
visualize as smooth line=my data, my data={smooth cycle}}}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes,
                       visualize as smooth cycle
                      ]
    data {
          x, y
          0, 1
          1, 2
          2, 1
         };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think someone should [report the issue](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues). If you do not want to do that I will be happy to do it.

Comment: Hello @Schrödinger's cat! Thank you for your answer! This visualizer makes no sense for me (it didn't also not as I found this in the manual), this is naturally only my opinion. You gladly can report this (I also don't have a GitHub account). When we are at this point, than I ask you to do it for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398720/how-can-one-change-all-arrow-tips-in-circuitikz-globally) also. An other wish: `datavisualization` have a visualizer `as scatter`, I would to like an additional visualizer `as circle` which works equal to the `as scatter`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 I added the issue and agree with you that the `visualize as smooth cycle` key may not be the most useful key to have. `visualize as circle` already exists, see e.g. the example on p. 929 of the manual v3.1.5. I will see what I can do with regards to circuitiz, which I hardly ever use. I want to avoid reporting something that experts have already resolved.

Comment: Hello @Schrödinger's cat! You are right about the `visualize as circle`. Don't know why I didn't found it earlier. Let me know if my wish for the `CircuiTikZ` fructify. Anyway a lot of thanks for your effort and time! If you have time, please look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518234/how-to-customize-tick-text-in-tikz).